# sqlite timestamp in where clause

Tags: sqlite

I was trying to do this:

```
SELECT SUM(price) as total FROM ticketLine WHERE dateRegistered > '2011-07-16 17:00:00'
```

The idea is (was) to get a total for all lines from 17:00 till now but I get a grand total for all lines. The where clause has no effect. I googled how to do a filter on a timestamp but got no relevant info.

Can you point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT * FROM ticketLine WHERE dateRegistered > '2011-07-16 17:00:00'`?

Comment: No, I asked what happens if your run `SELECT * ...` instead of `SELECT SUM(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry it took so long to answer this but here is the way to do it:

```
SELECT SUM(price) as total FROM ticketLine WHERE dateRegistered > DATETIME('2011-07-16 17:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure(I have never used SQLite, but I worked with MySQL and SQL Server), but there shoud be some functions to work with dates and time
Try this

`SELECT SUM(price) as total FROM ticketLine WHERE strftime('%s', dateRegistered) > strftime('%s', '2011-07-16 17:00:00')`

I hope it is helpfull.